# ¿Por qué no puedo leer archivos en C++ con QT pero si con CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, archivo, qt, codeblocks

Tengo el problema de que con CodeBlocks puedo leer un archivo que tengo almacenado pero con QT no puedo usando el mismo código.

**Este es el código que tengo en QT**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

void lectura();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    lectura();

    return a.exec();
}


void lectura(){
    std::ifstream entrada;
    std::string frase;

    entrada.open("Archivo.csv", std::ios::in);

    if(entrada.is_open()){

        while(!entrada.eof()){
            getline(entrada, frase);
            std::cout<<frase<<std::endl;
        }


    }else{
        frase = "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        std::cout<<"Frase leida: "<<frase<<"\n";
    }

    entrada.close();
}
```

Y sus archivos quedan de esta manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura del proyecto queda así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar este proyecto ma lanza al `else` mostrándome el mensaje que contiene la variable `frase`.

**Y cuando utilizo CodeBlocks con el siguiente código**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>



using namespace std;

void lectura();

int main()
{
    lectura();

    return 0;
}


void lectura(){

    ifstream entrada;
    std::string texto;

    entrada.open("Archivo.csv", ios::in);

    if(entrada.is_open()){

        while(!entrada.eof()){
            getline(entrada, texto);
            cout<<texto<<endl;
        }

    }else{
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo"<<endl;
    }


    entrada.close();

}
```

Los archivos quedan de esta forma...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me lee perfectamente el archivo y lo muestra en la consola.
Entonces no entiendo que puede estar pasando si el código es el mismo.

O necesito algún permiso para leer archivos en QT para poder continuar.

Ahora mismo puedo continuar con CodeBlocks pero preferiría no hacerlo porque en el pasado he tenido problemas con él por bugs en el programa.

Resalto que utilizo Ubuntu 18.04.

Agradezco las respuestas.

Comment: Recientemente me pasó que el `working directory` no coincidía con el directorio de compilado en xcode para mac. Quizas te pase lo mismo con este ide. Creo que puedes cambiarlo como muestra el link https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html Si es que esto responde a tu pregunta, podría redactarlo como respuesta :P

Comment: Cuando compilas desde Qt Creator te crea un directorio al mismo nivel que el de tu proyecto llamado build-nombreproyecto-KitUsado-Debug/Release (según compiles en modo Debug o Release). Dentro de ese directorio está el ejecutable y desde esa ruta buscará el archivo csv. Prueba a copiarlo ahí a ver si lo lee. Por otro lado CodeBlocks parece que también mete el ejecutable en un directorio propio, pero en este caso no sé por qué sí te lo lee.